# C# WPF - Grid MouseUp not firing due to previous Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, mouseup

I seems like the MouseUp event of my inner Grid isn't firing, because of the MouseDown Event from the surrounding Grid. Any way I can prevent this?

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1" Background="#00000000">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="495,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Background="#FF000000" MouseEnter="gridBtn_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="gridBtn_MouseLeave" MouseUp="gridBtn"/>             
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Could be an issue in your `MouseEnter` or `MouseLeave` event that is keeping `MouseUp` event from firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested the following and it works without problems.

```
    private void gridBtn(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseUp inner grid");
    }

    private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseDown outer grid");
    }

    private void gridBtn_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseEnter inner grid");
    }

    private void gridBtn_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseLeave inner grid");
    }
```

[image: MouseDown and Mouseup]

i just changed the colors for the grids to make it easy for me to see.
i hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You never receive `MouseDown` for the second grid, hence no `MouseUp` for the second grid. In order for the `MouseDown` event to propagate to the child you probably need to handle [PreviewMouseDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown(v=vs.110).aspx) to have a first crack at the event. You would then perform some kind of hit-testing.

Anyway, the *reason* your handler is not called is probably due to `e.Handled = true`.

E.g.:

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Uncomment to allow the MouseUp event for the second grid.
    e.Handled = true;
}
```